# can't run containers in javaee correctly

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, java-ee-6

I am getting acquainted with Docker and i need to inject it to my application. I have some problems:

My container always fall down and restarts, may be somebody faced a docker-compose in JavaEE application with MySQL.

My dockerfile:

```
FROM maven:3.6.3-jdk-11

COPY ./ ./

RUN mvn clean package

CMD ["java", "-war","target/javaee_rest_jdbc_todo_list.war"]
```

docker-compose file

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  api_service:
    build: .
    hostname: api_service
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8090:8080
    depends_on:
      - mysql_db
  mysql_db:
    image: "mysql:8.0"
    hostname: mysql_db
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3308:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: javaee_task_db
      MYSQL_USER: user228
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: user228
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 13574637480326
```

Also i have flyway plugin in my pom.xml file:

```
        <plugin>
          <groupId>com.googlecode.flyway</groupId>
          <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>1.5</version>
          <configuration>
            <user>user228</user>
            <password>user228</password>
            <driver>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver>
            <url>jdbc:mysql://mysql_db:3308/javaee_task_db?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci&amp;characterSetResults=UTF-8</url>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

And my dataSourse url connection:

```
    final static String URL = "jdbc:mysql://mysql_db:3308/javaee_task_db?useSSL=false";
```

I also attach link to github - https://github.com/MatveyAndrosyukk/javaee_rest_jdbc_todo_list.

I will be veery grateful for your help!

Comment: error logs would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

First issue I notice is that the DataSourse URL should use the DB port within a docker network, i.e., `3306`

Comment: why? in my docker-compose i set  `ports:  - 3308:3306`. I tryed to change in datasourse on 3306, but it falls anyway(

Comment: because 3308 is a port that is exposed on host, your containerized application should use the port which is in the same docker network

Comment: check the container logs first, there you will likely see why it fails

Comment: `Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Unrecognized option: -war`  This is log error, but i don't understand, what i have to fix? May be war archives shoul'd be run in another way?

Comment: looks like that :D war files should be deployed to Tomcat server, please check this if it helps https://www.baeldung.com/docker-deploy-java-war

Comment: Okey, i did it, `FROM tomcat

COPY target/javaee_rest_jdbc_todo_list.war /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/` , but it falls anyway(  Also when i build image and run container of my app separately, it is shown, that it is run

Comment: any errors in the logs?

Comment: okey, now in is working, but when i try to connect in browser, i get 404 error `The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.` I pushed it to github, can you check, please?